# Creating a domain in Plesk's REST API

Tags: rest, plesk, plesk-onyx

So, experimenting with Plesk's REST API (available as of version 17.8) for a project at work, and I'm starting to get a feel for it.  I've been trying to experiment with adding a domain, but it's been giving me errors when I have to specify the hosting type.

The request body itself is as follows:

`{
    "name":"example.com",
    "hosting_type":"virtual",
    "description":"Description goes here"
}`

This gets the following cryptic response:

`{
    "code": 1014,
    "message": "htype\/vrt_hst is specified but there is no hosting\/vrt_hst"
}`

Per the documentation provided at `/api/v2/swagger.yml`, any of the following values should be allowed: `virtual`, `standard_forwarding`, `frame_forwarding`, `none`

No matter what I put in, however, I get a variant of the response above (`htype\/{type} is specified but there is no hosting\/{type}`).

At this point I'm kind of stuck; I'm not sure what to check, and any references when I try to look up the error code go to references on Plesk's XML API instead.  What's the missing link here needed to get the request to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like system user is not specified - hosting_settings. Try to add domain with full json request. Here is example:

```
{
  "name": "example.com",
  "description": "My website",
  "hosting_type": "virtual",
  "hosting_settings": {
    "ftp_login": "test_login",
    "ftp_password": "test_pwd"
  },
  "base_domain": {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "a10-52-41-48.qa.plesk.ru",
    "guid": "b623e93d-dc72-4102-b5f0-ded427cf0fb1"
  },
  "parent_domain": {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "a10-52-41-48.qa.plesk.ru",
    "guid": "b623e93d-dc72-4102-b5f0-ded427cf0fb1"
  },
  "owner_client": {
    "id": 7,
    "login": "a10-52-41-48.qa.plesk.ru",
    "guid": "b623e93d-dc72-4102-b5f0-ded427cf0fb1",
    "external_id": "b623e93d-dc72-4102-b5f0-ded427cf0fb1"
  },
  "ipv4": [
    "212.192.122.46"
  ],
  "ipv6": [
    "2002:5bcc:18fd:c:123:123:123:123"
  ],
  "plan": {
    "name": "Unlimited"
  }
}
```

Examples for REST API https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/plesk/api/v2#/Domains/post_domains

Comment: That documentation is much more helpful than what I was using before.  Short answer is that it needed the hosting_settings, as you pointed out, but it doesn't seem to actually create a new FTP account for it, even though every new account requires a unique one, even if hosting_type is set to `none`.  Will probably post a separate response shortly with some more details, but at least wanted to recognize you for providing the necessary direction to get it working pre the original question.  Now to see if there's a way to specify the home directory for the domain...